# How to store Unique=True in database in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-import-export

My app keeps book records for different schools I have a Klass model that enables each school to key in the classes in the school. I also have an import-export resource for importing books details in bulk. I however get an error because already there are two schools each having form 1 form 2 and form 3. It return `MultipleObjectsReturned` error

```
get() returned more than one Klass -- it returned 2!
```

How can I help my situation???

```
class ImportStudentsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    school = fields.Field(attribute = 'school',column_name='school', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(School, 'name'))
    klass = fields.Field(attribute = 'klass',column_name='class', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Klass, 'name'))
    stream = fields.Field(attribute = 'stream',column_name='stream', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Stream, 'name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')
        import_id_fields = ('student_id',)
        import_order = ('school','student_id','name','year','klass','stream')

class uploadStudents(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    context = {}
    def get(self,request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm()
        self.context['form'] = form
        return render(request,'libman/upload_student.html',self.context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = UploadStudentsForm(request.POST , request.FILES)
        data_set = Dataset()
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file']
            extension = file.name.split(".")[-1].lower()
            resource = ImportStudentsResource()
            if extension == 'csv':
                data = data_set.load(file.read().decode('utf-8'), format=extension)
            else:
                data = data_set.load(file.read(), format=extension)
            result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=True, collect_failed_rows=True, raise_errors=True)
            if result.has_validation_errors() or result.has_errors():
                messages.success(request,f'Errors experienced during import.')
                print("error", result.invalid_rows)
                self.context['result'] = result
                return redirect('upload_students')                
            else:
                result = resource.import_data(data_set, dry_run=False, raise_errors=False)
                self.context['result'] = None
                messages.success(request,f'Students uploaded successfully.')                
        else:
            self.context['form'] = UploadStudentsForm()

        return render(request, 'libman/upload_student.html', self.context)

class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    YEAR = [(str(a), str(a)) for a in range(now.year-2, now.year+2)]
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices = YEAR)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stream = models.ForeignKey(Stream,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Setting klass field as unique will also raise an error when I try creating the same class for another school...

Comment: You need to add a primary key to all your entries.

Comment: How would I do that??????

Comment: @kinshukdua Django creates a primary key automatically, if not told explicit to _not_ do so

Answer (score 1):

Your title and question are a bit confusing, but I think this is likely occurring because whenever you import your data, the logic cannot uniquely identify a unique instance of 'klass'.  You are using the 'name' attribute of the foreign key relationship to class.  Ensure that the 'name' uniquely identifies a single instance of Klass.

If name is not unique, then you could consider using a unique field, such as the Klass primary key.  If this is not possible, then you would have to come up with some way of uniquely identifying the Klass to use in the FK relationship, perhaps using a combination of fields (school + class?).   You would have to subclass `ForeignKeyWidget` to handle this case.

[ForeignKeyWidget docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget)

Comment: I'm struggling with this. Please help with an example on how to go about this, please.

Comment: start by looking at the 'class' column in your import file, find the entry which returns > 1 result from the Klass table. [This](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/01ab0255d31ea63481ac3a78edd6fb9442e26320/import_export/widgets.py#L393) is the source of the error.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it this to work, finer explanations,please....